# How to auto scale PersistentVolume = replicas use Statefulset when install or upgrade values in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i created Helm use Statefulset. In Statefulset i mount volume to pod use volumeClaimTemplates with storageClassName A given.

With replica = 1 in values file, it will auto create PV from storageClassName with pv.yaml then pv auto create pvc

With replica >= 2 in values file, pv.yaml only create 1 pv and it will wrong in this case. Ex: If replica = 2 => create 2 pv, else if replica = 4 => create 4 pv

How i setting function auto scale or create pv if replica >= 2 (When install and upgrade helm if modify replica param)
This is my manisfest statefulset.yaml in helm. I use volumeClaimTemplates to auto create pvc when per increase use replicas. But i dont know how to dynamic create pv when per increase use replicas in helm

```
volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: {{ .Values.volumeClaimTemplates.mountPath }}
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      storageClassName: local-storage-immediate
      accessModes: {{ .Values.volumeClaimTemplates.accessModes }}
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: {{ .Values.volumeClaimTemplates.size }}
```

This is my manifest PV.yaml. I dont know how to create this in yalm to autoscale PV per pod increase instead create it manually

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mdcore-core-data
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: "local-storage-immediate"
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Comment: Can you show what is in your `pv.yaml`? Are you using the `volumeclaimtemplates` in your statefulset?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually create PersistentVolumes; the cluster should be running a storage provisioner that will create them for you.  So each StatefulSet replica gets a new automatically-created PersistentVolumeClaim which in turn gets a new automatically-created PersistentVolume.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello everyone, i provide code

Comment: Hello @jordanm, i provide my manifest